# Symfony: Gulp assets inheritance

Tags: symfony, templates, gulp, assets

Is there any util with we can build project using gulp on vendor/src files same as symfony assetic system?

I mean bundle inheritance.

My gulp is set on vendor files and compile resources to web catalog, but i didn't found possibility that gulp recognize if files were override by my bundle in src/ catalog

Comment: I'm using Gulp with Symfony too. You must use the direct direct path of your files and compile / copy them to web folder. I don't know exactly what you want to do

Comment: a tool that automatically recognize if file is overrided and use that overrided file to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use the plugin `Gulp Watch`  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch/) and make a `watch` task that will check if a file changed.

If a file change you gulp `watch` task will launch another task to compile your files or just copy them.

Your `watch` should look like this

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(app + '/scss/**/*.scss', ['sass']); // If a scss file change it will run my sass task
    gulp.watch(app + '/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,svg}', ['images']); // If there is a new image it will run my images task
});
```

You can do it with other file `html` `js` etc

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, it's seems to be little work to watch and handle every bundle, but it's accepted answer.